# Activating Sierra Finder Window options

Tags: finder

In Finder in Sierra, in the menu Window, all options are disabled. How can I activate them?

Answer (score 1):

All options in the Window menu will be inactive when there's no Finder window. You can simply create a new one via the menu File -> New Finder Window, or by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.